# WPF: MenuItem inside toolbar border issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, toolbar

I have toolbar and I need to add menu as a part of it (toolbar combines both menus and single click buttons). Everything works fine except a small visual issue.

When menu is opened it is nicely connected to the toolbar (it is inside the same border). However, when menu is on an edge of a screen it will open slightly to the left, but the gap in the menu border stays on the left. Any ideas on how to correclty align the gap?

[image]

Sample code:

```
    <ToolBarTray IsLocked="True">
        <ToolBar>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item">
                    <MenuItem Header="Item" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your **ToolBarTray** code inside **Grid** should restrict it from going outside.

Comment: This will not work, if there is not enough space on the screen.

Comment: Open menu "windows" are disconnected from the visual tree in WPF, so  placing them inside a grid won't necessarily contain them.